# How to get the last item of a list in python

Tags: python, list

I started learning python a few day ago

I tried to make program of anime watchlist. I tested to include also adding new ones but when I'm trying to print out a new, added one, I am only getting a letter. How I can get a full text? There's code

```
anime_list = ["one piece","fullmetal alchemist", "my hero academia", "oregairu", "jojo", "jujutsu kaisen"]

a_o_s = input ("What do you want to do ('add anime' or 'what I should watch?')\n")

if a_o_s == "add anime":
    anime_list = input ("What anime do you want to add?\n")
    print("thank you " + anime_list[anime_list -1] + " is added")
```

I tried too to just print every letter from the start of a name to an end but it doesn't work either

```
anime_list = ["one piece","fullmetal alchemist", "my hero academia", "oregairu", "jojo", "jujutsu kaisen"]

a_o_s = input ("What do you want to do ('add anime' or 'what I should watch?')\n")

if a_o_s == "add anime":
    anime_list = input ("What anime do you want to add?\n")
    n_w = anime_list.count
    print("thank you " + anime_list[n_w:-1] + " is added")
```

Is there any way to do it?

thank you

Comment: `anime_list[anime_list -1]` should be `anime_list[-1]`

Comment: Might I suggest that you read the tutorial. The part about [lists](https://docs.python.org/3.10/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) is in the third chapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `anime_list = input ("What anime do you want to add?\n")` you redefine `anime_list`. Now it's not a list anymore but a string (the return value from `input`). You have to append the data to the list. The last element can be accessed at index -1.

```
anime_list = ["one piece", "fullmetal alchemist", "my hero academia", "oregairu", "jojo", "jujutsu kaisen"]
anime_list.append(input("What anime do you want to add?\n"))
print(f"thank you, {anime_list[-1]} was added")
```

Answer (score 0):

when you want to get the last item of a list you can simply write ***name_of_your_list[-1]*** so for this instance you can do:

```
anime_list[-1]
```

which will give you the last item in the list